# Not able to connect with socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need some help concerning socket.io-client. I try to connect a node.js script with a node.js server. The server works fine an communicates with the Clients (browser).

My problem is, that I am not able to define the socket.io-client script in my mentioned node.js script. Here is an image of my problem:

[image]

I always get the red line below the io. According to the documentation on Github it should be fine... What is my mistake? I am using version: "socket.io-client": "^3.1.1"

Happy for some help! Thanks!

Comment: Does this code run? I think it just IDE trouble

Answer (score 0):

I run it several times. It´s weird. The code runs and I get a connection... looks like it is working... it is just IDE trouble... THANKS!!